# SAML authentication request for the WebSSO profile must not specify any SubjectConfirmations

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs

I'm developing **ADFS** related project with **SAML 2.0** protocol. My application is acting as **ServiceProvider**. When I typed my credentials and clicked on **sign in** button, an error occurred. The error statement is **An error occurred. Contact your administrator for more information.** When I checked the **Event Viewer** of my **windows Server 2012** at which **ADFS** is installed, it displays the below error detail

**Data** Saml

**Data** http://DomainName/adfs/services/trust

**Data** Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSignatureVerificationException: MSIS7075: SAML authentication request for the WebSSO profile must not specify any SubjectConfirmations. at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.ValidateSignatureRequirements(SamlMessage samlMessage) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

Comment: This rings a bell. Refer https://support.pingidentity.com/s/article/SSO-with-ADFS-to-PingOne-results-in-We-have-received-an-unsuccessful-response-from-your-IDP-results-and-SSO-login-fails

Comment: @lacey do you still need help for this one?

Comment: Can you please paste the SAML request here? Feel free to rub any private URLs as needed.